# Trino "SHOW SCHEMAS" filter

Tags: trino

Is there any way to tell Trino to **exclude** those schemas that a user doesn't have access to from being shown in the "SHOW SCHEMAS in {catalog}" command output.

Even if the schema isn't accessible it's still really insecure to show schema names to users that are not intended to see/use it.

Thanks in advance,